# Merge tags [throttle] and [throttling]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

[throttling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/throttling) is `Throttling is a mechanism to regulate the rate at which processing is performed`

and [throttle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/throttle) is `A throttle is a mechanism to regulate the rate at which processing is performed`

I propose merging throttle into [throttling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/throttling).

Comment: Please specify if it is [synonym-request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/synonym-request) or [retag-request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/retag-request).

Comment: @VadimKotov I am not sure actually. I put retag-request as I don't think there's a point of having both around, but I'd be happy to hear otherwise

Comment: Ok, I think you can change it later based on discussion/feedback.